# Find a polygon by attribute Google map engine

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, attributes, shapefile, google-maps-engine

I created a map via Google map Engine, (not the lite/pro).

And then added an uploaded [shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) given to me as a data source. I've successfully published the map and access links are now available, either for embedding, kml, or the Asset ID.

So I've rendered the map inside my application that looks like this :

[image: shape map]

So it's really great, each polygon has a set of attributes, like OBJECTID_1, and so on.

What I would like to ask is that, can I have some sort of text area wherein I could type in an **value for an attribute** (atleast the **OBJECTID_1**-which is sort of the ID of the polygon/area) and then submit to **trigger a click event on that polygon** found to show its attributes (like the one shown in the pic), or zoom in to that area. I'm not so familiar with the technology, but given API access, would it be possible via web service/something?

Basically how to find a polygon from the numerous polygons defined, given it's OBJECTID_1. Thanks!

Comment: Update! To help you test here is the asset ID : 07732892464132847854-05414812628978701557, or you can actually ask what access link would actually suit the need to simulate the problem. I really appreciate the help thanks

Comment: *or you can actually ask what access link would actually suit the need to simulate the problem*  ...a public accessible source would be a good start, this asset doesn't seem to be public

Comment: I've made it public does it do anything?

Comment: Post the code where you create the polygons or at least a link to your page.

Comment: @muffin: to be able to access your data we need 1.(to create the mapsEngineLayer) the Asset-ID of the layer or the Asset-ID of the map + the layer key of the layer 2.(to access  the vector table...required to search for particula features): the Asset-ID of the vector table. All mentioned assets must be public available(publish version).

Answer (score 0):

As this is a programming forum I'll try and give you the programming answer. If you're looking for how to use the Maps Engine product, you'll need to ask elsewhere (perhaps the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-engine-users)).

You can search for features using the [Table.features:list](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables/features/list) call in the API. Specifically, you want the 'where' parameter, that allows you to specify a value like `OBJECTID_1=myvalue` to search by OBJECTID_1.

If you are displaying this on a map, the JavaScript API's [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) will make your life easier, as it can display the results of the feature list request directly on a map.